# MongoDB Node JS escaping single quote problems

Tags: php, node.js, mongodb

In my Node js, I have escaped single quote with the below function

```
var regescape = function(text) {
return text.replace(/[\[\]']+/g, "\\$&"); 
};
```

This is working fine for me.
But suddenly I discovered I have a string M'$ in my database. Which is not returning with my below query.

```
param 1 = "M'$";

var cursor = db.collection('search').find({"searchcontent.name":new RegExp('^'+regescape(param1))}).limit(10);
```

Also Please suggest the best practice for handling Node JS parameter pass to MongoDB. 
I am calling NodeJS from PHP code. And I am sending parameters with `rawurlencode()` from PHP code. In node js I'm using `decodeURI()` to the received parameters.

**Edit:**

My PHP code for calling Node JS:

```
function getdetail($data1) {
    $p1 = $data1;
    $service_url = 'http://exampleserver:8081/search?param1='.$p1;
    $curl = curl_init($service_url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
        if ($curl_response === false) {
        $info = curl_getinfo($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        die('error occured.Please try later');
        }
    curl_close($curl);
    $decoded = json_decode($curl_response, true);
    if (isset($decoded->response->status) && $decoded->response->status == 'ERROR') {
        die('error occured.Please try later');
    }
    return $decoded;

}
```

Node JS code to receive data:

```
app.get('/search', function (req, res) {
    var param1=decodeURI(req.query.param1);
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
     assert.equal(null, err);
     search(param1,db, function(data){ db.close(); res.end(JSON.stringify(data)); });
   });
});


var search = function(param1,db, callback) {

var cursor = db.collection('search').find({$or:[{"searchcontent.name":new RegExp('^'+regescape(param1))},{"searchcontent.name":new RegExp('^'+regescape(param1.substring(0,4)))}]}).limit(10);

    cursor.toArray(function(err, items) {
    callback(items);
    });

  };
```

This Node JS code is for search so I used `RegEXP()`. For other cases I used the below code:

```
var cursor = db.collection('employees').find({"dep.name":regescape(param1),"mrg.name":regescape(param2)});
```

Comment: Is there a need for regex search here?

Comment: Yes. Its my website's Search query. so regex is needed

Comment: How are you calling node.js? Through "curl" or through command line? How are you receiving parameters in NodeJS - using Express,  or...? As for the regex, do you need the ^ as that indicates "start of line"? Would help if you show how you're inputting the entries into Mongo to validate the search.

Comment: you just want to find M'$ or you are not sure if there can be any other occurrences  of such char sequence in your db. can your db contains $'M or MM'$, what is your focus here ? just retrieve M'$ ?

Comment: (\w+|\W+)(\')(\W+|\w+)  will match any word or non-word (in your case $) occurrences  followed by ' followed by any word or non-word occurrences. let me know if this worked for you or not.

Comment: @Robbie I updated the Question. Please check.

Comment: @satishchennupati Its not working

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with $ sign. It's a special character and it should be escaped, because normally it means end of input. You have to update `regescape` function, because it escapes only single quote and square brackets - so you have at least add dollar sign there too.

Also seems like your `regescape` function does not work as expected in some cases. Try for example to pass this value: `test[]'`. I think you expect to get `test\[\]\'`, but actually you will get `test\[]'`

So in order to fix it and add dolar sign - it should be something like this:

```
var regescape = function(text) {
    return text.replace(/'|\$|\[|\]/g, "\\$&"); 
};
```

Pipe (|) means `or`, so it simply escapes any of the symbols from the set. You can easily add more characters there in future.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. This is working for the particular case M'$. But its not working for the regular cases. For example consider this string  "He's Name" . so if there is only single quote, its not working.

Comment: @Arijit what exactly not working? `regescape` function or MongoDB search? `regescape` returns `He\'s name` with escaped single quote.

Comment: Yes that's true, but when I am using the escaped parameter in mongodb its not returning any result. Consider this node js query to mongodb:   var cursor = db.collection('employees').find({"dep.name":regescape(param1),"mrg.name":regescape(param2)});

Comment: Why do you need to escape string for plain search? I  think you need to escape string only for regex search.

Comment: If I use "dep.name":param1‌​ instead of "dep.name":regescape(param1‌​) then also no result is displaying for strings having single quotes.

Comment: @Arijit I tried to reproduce your issue and everything works fine on my side.
What is the value of `param1` before searching? Maybe you have issues with upper and lower case?